# using SendGrid in Java based Azure web site

Tags: java, azure, azure-web-app-service, sendgrid

I want to using SendGrid for sending emails from my web app. I went through this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/store-sendgrid-java-how-to-send-email/)

I am unable to proceed with the help of this above mentioned article. Can any one help me please?

Comment: Please describe what you did till now from that article and what exactly problem you facing.

Comment: I read that article. but I'am not getting where and how to start from.

Answer (score 1):

Use sendgrid-java. It is pretty straight forward to send emails using this library.

```
    SendGrid sendgrid = new SendGrid('YOUR_SENDGRID_API_KEY');

    SendGrid.Email email = new SendGrid.Email();
    email.addTo("example@example.com");
    email.setFrom("other@example.com");
    email.setSubject("Hello World");
    email.setText("My first email with SendGrid Java!");

    try {
      SendGrid.Response response = sendgrid.send(email);
      System.out.println(response.getMessage());
    }
    catch (SendGridException e) {
      System.err.println(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Anil said, you can tried to send emails using the SendGrid SDK for Java, please see the library on GitHub https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java, or directly add its [maven dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sendgrid/sendgrid-java/) below into your maven project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
    <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The other way is using the SendGrid REST API via HTTP using the Class `HTTPConnection` in Java, please see the docs for [WebAPI v2](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/index.html) or [WebAPI v3](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/index.html).